# How to use Microsoft.Maui.Essentials?

Tags: maui

How can I setup Microsoft.Maui.Essentials in my MAUI app? I read that it comes by default with .NET 6 which I have installed but whenever I use the Microsoft.Maui.Essentials; an error message appears:

```
The type or namespace name 'Essentials' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Maui' (are you missing an assembly reference
```

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Had you tired to use the api you want without adding the namespace?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Essentials as a name(space) has gone away at some point. All the APIs are now devided in more logical namespaces. You can see the PR for that [here](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/pull/5562). But let me add the list of APIs and their new namespaces here as well:

```cs
namespace Microsoft.Maui.Accessibility {
    public interface ISemanticScreenReader {}
    public static class SemanticScreenReader {}
}
namespace Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel {
    public enum ActivityState {}
    public class ActivityStateChangedEventArgs : EventArgs {}
    public class AppAction {}
    public class AppActionEventArgs : EventArgs {}
    public static class AppActions {}
    public static class AppInfo {}
    public enum AppPackagingModel {}
    public enum AppTheme {}
    public static class Browser {}
    public enum BrowserLaunchFlags {}
    public enum BrowserLaunchMode {}
    public class BrowserLaunchOptions {}
    public enum BrowserTitleMode {}
    public class FeatureNotEnabledException : InvalidOperationException {}
    public class FeatureNotSupportedException : NotSupportedException {}
    public interface IAppActions {}
    public interface IAppInfo {}
    public interface IBrowser {}
    public interface ILauncher {}
    public interface IMap {}
    public interface IVersionTracking {}
    public static class Launcher {}
    public enum LayoutDirection {}
    public static class MainThread {}
    public static class Map {}
    public class MapLaunchOptions {}
    public enum NavigationMode {}
    public class OpenFileRequest {}
    public class PermissionException : UnauthorizedAccessException {}
    public static class Permissions {}
    public enum PermissionStatus {}
    public static class Platform {}
    public static class VersionTracking {}
}
namespace Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.Communication {
    public class Contact {}
    public class ContactEmail {}
    public class ContactPhone {}
    public static class Contacts {}
    public static class Email {}
    public class EmailAttachment : FileBase {}
    public enum EmailBodyFormat {}
    public class EmailMessage {}
    public interface IContacts {}
    public interface IEmail {}
    public interface IPhoneDialer {}
    public interface ISms {}
    public static class PhoneDialer {}
    public static class Sms {}
    public class SmsMessage {}
}
namespace Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer {
    public static class Clipboard {}
    public interface IClipboard {}
    public interface IShare {}
    public static class Share {}
    public class ShareFile : FileBase {}
    public class ShareFileRequest : ShareRequestBase {}
    public class ShareMultipleFilesRequest : ShareRequestBase {}
    public abstract class ShareRequestBase {}
    public class ShareTextRequest : ShareRequestBase {}
}
namespace Microsoft.Maui.Authentication {
    public static class AppleSignInAuthenticator {}
    public interface IAppleSignInAuthenticator {}
    public interface IPlatformWebAuthenticatorCallback {}
    public interface IWebAuthenticator {}
    public static class WebAuthenticator {}
    public abstract class WebAuthenticatorCallbackActivity : Activity {}
    public class WebAuthenticatorOptions {}
    public class WebAuthenticatorResult {}
}
namespace Microsoft.Maui.Devices {
    public static class Battery {}
    public class BatteryInfoChangedEventArgs : EventArgs {}
    public enum BatteryPowerSource {}
    public enum BatteryState {}
    public static class DeviceDisplay {}
    public readonly struct DeviceIdiom : IEquatable<DeviceIdiom> {}
    public static class DeviceInfo {}
    public readonly struct DevicePlatform : IEquatable<DevicePlatform> {}
    public enum DeviceType {}
    public readonly struct DisplayInfo : IEquatable<DisplayInfo> {}
    public class DisplayInfoChangedEventArgs : EventArgs {}
    public enum DisplayOrientation {}
    public enum DisplayRotation {}
    public enum EnergySaverStatus {}
    public class EnergySaverStatusChangedEventArgs : EventArgs {}
    public static class Flashlight {}
    public static class HapticFeedback {}
    public enum HapticFeedbackType {}
    public interface IBattery {}
    public interface IDeviceDisplay {}
    public interface IDeviceInfo {}
    public interface IFlashlight {}
    public interface IHapticFeedback {}
    public interface IVibration {}
    public static class Vibration {}
}
namespace Microsoft.Maui.Devices.Sensors {
    public static class Accelerometer {}
    public class AccelerometerChangedEventArgs : EventArgs {}
    public readonly struct AccelerometerData : IEquatable<AccelerometerData> {}
    public enum AltitudeReferenceSystem {}
    public static class Barometer {}
    public class BarometerChangedEventArgs : EventArgs {}
    public readonly struct BarometerData : IEquatable<BarometerData> {}
    public static class Compass {}
    public class CompassChangedEventArgs : EventArgs {}
    public readonly struct CompassData : IEquatable<CompassData> {}
    public enum DistanceUnits {}
    public static class Geocoding {}
    public static class Geolocation {}
    public enum GeolocationAccuracy {}
    public class GeolocationRequest {}
    public static class Gyroscope {}
    public class GyroscopeChangedEventArgs : EventArgs {}
    public readonly struct GyroscopeData : IEquatable<GyroscopeData> {}
    public interface IAccelerometer {}
    public interface IBarometer {}
    public interface ICompass {}
    public interface IGeocoding {}
    public interface IGeolocation {}
    public interface IGyroscope {}
    public interface IMagnetometer {}
    public interface IOrientationSensor {}
    public interface IPlatformCompass {}
    public class Location {}
    public static class LocationExtensions {}
    public static class Magnetometer {}
    public class MagnetometerChangedEventArgs : EventArgs {}
    public readonly struct MagnetometerData : IEquatable<MagnetometerData> {}
    public static class OrientationSensor {}
    public class OrientationSensorChangedEventArgs : EventArgs {}
    public readonly struct OrientationSensorData : IEquatable<OrientationSensorData> {}
    public class Placemark {}
    public static class PlacemarkExtensions {}
    public enum SensorSpeed {}
}
namespace Microsoft.Maui.Media {
    public interface IMediaPicker {}
    public interface IScreenshot {}
    public interface IScreenshotResult {}
    public interface ITextToSpeech {}
    public class Locale {}
    public static class MediaPicker {}
    public class MediaPickerOptions {}
    public static class Screenshot {}
    public static class ScreenshotExtensions {}
    public enum ScreenshotFormat {}
    public class SpeechOptions {}
    public static class TextToSpeech {}
    public static class UnitConverters {}
}
namespace Microsoft.Maui.Networking {
    public enum ConnectionProfile {}
    public static class Connectivity {}
    public class ConnectivityChangedEventArgs : EventArgs {}
    public interface IConnectivity {}
    public enum NetworkAccess {}
}
namespace Microsoft.Maui.Storage {
    public abstract class FileBase {}
    public static class FilePicker {}
    public class FilePickerFileType {}
    public class FileProvider : FileProvider {}
    public enum FileProviderLocation {}
    public class FileResult : FileBase {}
    public static class FileSystem {}
    public interface IFileSystem {}
    public interface IPlatformFileSystem {}
    public interface IPlatformSecureStorage {}
    public interface IPreferences {}
    public interface ISecureStorage {}
    public class PickOptions {}
    public static class Preferences {}
    public class ReadOnlyFile : FileBase {}
    public static class SecureStorage {}
}
```

Comment: If I want to use some functionality in Microsoft.Maui.Essentials in a .net iOS app, can I install a package on my .Net iOS project?

Comment: Yes. Add the `<UseMauiEssentials>true</UseMauiEssentials>` property to your csproj file and then add the following package `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Essentials" Version="8.0.3" />` to add Maui Essentials to a native .NET iOS app.