# package Microsoft.Maui.Essentials

Tags: android, .net, maui

but how to have the Microsoft.Maui.Essentials library then the package does not want to install .I even tried to add the reference in the visualstudio console but it does not work

Comment: Please be a lot more specific than "the package does not want to install". How exactly have you tried to add a reference, and what exactly happened?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [the Library Microsoft.Maui.Essentials .Net Maui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75578744/the-library-microsoft-maui-essentials-net-maui)

Comment: You asked this yesterday and it was closed.  Please do NOT post duplicates questions

Comment: sorry; but I need an answer please ; the answer I got yesterday did not help me

Comment: Essentials is now built in to MAUI.  It is not a separate package you need to install

Comment: yes ok but for what in using Microsoft.Maui.Essentials; the word Essentials is always underlined in red in my project .

Comment: Yes, you have already been directed to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72815747/how-to-use-microsoft-maui-essentials?rq=1) which explains how the Essentials classes have been mapped to more logical namespaces

Comment: Could you be more specific. Say what you have done, what error or problem happened, and what you want to achieve.

Comment: display data from an xml file upload from the mobile download folder in ListView

Answer (score 0):

Your other question about this got closed and [a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72815747/how-to-use-microsoft-maui-essentials) was linked. I'm sorry if that was not clear enough.

Microsoft.Maui.Essentials as a separate package might exist, but you don't have to install it separately on a .NET MAUI project. All the functionalities are already inside of .NET MAUI.

If you want to use the battery information just use the `Microsoft.Maui.Devices.Battery` object, no need for the NuGet package to be installed, it comes automatically as part of .NET MAUI itself.

Please refer to the duplicate linked issue, which I linked again above, for all the APIs that were previously known as Essentials and their current namespaces where they are now.

If you're looking for an API and how to use it, you can also use the https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/.

Comment: thank you for your answer and sorry for the duplicate of my question. I made a code to load an xml document from the download of my phone in a View list but when running, my View list is always empty, I need the Microsoft.Maui.Essentials library I even tried to add the reference in the visualstudio console but it does not work, please is there another way to load and take the data from the xml file to load from phone download folder.

Comment: Sure. Every plugin, framework or piece of code is just code someone else wrote to make your life easier. There is lots of ways to achieve what you want to do. Unfortunately, I don't have enough detail to understand what you are trying to do to be helpful here. You might want to try and open a new question with a good, extensive description of what you are trying to do, what doesn't work and what you have already tried to resolve it.