# MAUI Create a new Contact

Tags: save, contacts, maui

i have written a MAUI .NET 6 application and i want to create a new entry in my contactlist.

Earlier u can use the methode **Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Contacts.AddContactAsync**. But now the namespace Microsoft.Maui.Essentials is replaced by some others ([How to use Microsoft.Maui.Essentials?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72815747/how-to-use-microsoft-maui-essentials?rq=1)) and i can not find any method to save a new contact.

Has anyone an idea in which namespace this function is placed today?

Thanks for ur help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please be noted that the new namespaces are documented in the [Migrating to RC1 page](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/wiki/Migrating-to-RC1).

And the new namespace that is related with **Conatct** is `Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.Communication`. You can go through:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/communication/contacts?view=net-maui-6.0&tabs=android for more details.

Comment: Hello and thanks. I knew this new namespace but there isnt any method to create a new contact - only to pickup one. Thats also the reason for my question...

Comment: @esehigs Thanks for your update, for the `Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.Communication.Contacts`, you can only `pick a contact` and `get all contacts`, if you want to add or create a new contact, I suggest that you can get all the contacts and then assign it to an observablecollection and then you add the new contact to the observablecollection to reflect the changes of the new contact.

Comment: Thank for your reply but i dont understand how i can reflect the changes to my phone-contacts. I have tried the following: 
var contacts = await Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.Communication.Contacts.Default.GetAllAsync();
var osc = new ObservableCollection<Contact>(contacts);
osc.Add(newContact); 
And now?

Comment: You have almost done the work, the new contact has been added to `osc`, if you let the `osc` show on the `CollectionView`, you'll see the new added contact.

Comment: Sure, i see the new contact on an the CollectionView but the contact isnt saved in my phone-contacts and that is what i want. I only need a function to save the contact to my phone-contacts...

Comment: Per [Conatct](https://github.com/dotnet/docs-maui/blob/main/docs/platform-integration/communication/contacts.md#platform-differences),the `Contacts` is read-only for now and there's no open API or Interface for us to do the `add` operation. You may [open a discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions) here to confirm if the `add` operation can be added to the namespace.